# VBA | Macro functions will not compute worksheet data

Tags: excel, vba

When I use this code on my data, it does not generate data for columns 1, 2, or 6. I have values for the entire columns X, Y, and Z. I use CountA to find the value for i, with i=803 currently (corresponding to the number of rows of data in row X), but this needs to be variable (The reason I am calculating these simple variables is to use them in other code that calls the X, Y and Z values for each i). Can anyone see what I have formatted incorrectly?

```
Sub CalculateResults()
'Simple Worksheet Calculations
Dim Day As Variant
Dim DateTrue As Variant
Dim TF As Variant

For i = 0 To Cells(1, 1).Value

Day = Cells(3 + i, 1)
DateTrue = Cells(3 + i, 2)
X = Cells(3 + i, 3)
Y = Cells(3 + i, 4)
Z = Cells(3 + i, 5)
TF = Cells(3 + i, 6)

    'Worksheet Calculations
    Day = 0 + i
    DateTrue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Sheet2.Range("lookup_field[Field Start]")) + Day
    TF = X + Y + Z
Next i
End Sub
```

Many thanks mates.

Comment: Take a look at ncell = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row That gets the last line of Column A, then you make the For i=0 To ncell

Comment: Why do you set two different values for `TF` variant on your code? You don't use it between the two settings...

Comment: Really? Didn't know about it, gonna take a look

Comment: @danieltakeshi there are 1045876 rows in a xlsm sheet and if the data goes beyond the 65536 row then the `xlUp` will miss data, possibly all of it as it will go to the first empty cell, or row 1.  instead of `"A65536"` put `"A" & Rows.Count` then it does not matter the type of excel file it will always start at the last row.